# How to set a flag with shell "if" condition

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, environment

I am new to shell and I have never actually worked in it. I have a build script and i want to export a flag to "true" or "false" based on the condition in the if statement. 
My code is

```
echo "Is the Build with GAPPS?(arm64 only)"
set_gapps_build=false
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
case $yn in   
        Yes ) set_gapps_build=true;
        break;;
        No ) set_gapps_build=false;
        break;;
    esac
done
if [ "$set_gapps_build" = true ] ; then
        export SAKURA_GAPPS=true
        export TARGET_GAPPS_ARCH=arm64
fi
```

If i choose true, the flag should be set to true but its not working. It remains to false. Incase you want to see the whole shell code its here..
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LordShenron/build/master/build

Comment: How do you know it's false? How are you testing that?

Comment: After executing the script when i try to build, it asks again for the TARGET_GAPPS_ARCH. But that should already be set to arm64 with the script.

Comment: Don't use `bash script.sh` or `./script.sh`. Use `source script.sh` or `. script.sh`.

Comment: @Cyrus there is a weird problem when i use source or . script.sh, i just tried with it and at the end of the option it closed my ssh connection while in ./script.sh it did not.

Comment: If the script runs `exit` it will exit the entire ssh session when sourced

Comment: Yes i guess thats whats happening here. 
Is there no way to set the flag to true without source?

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for pointing towards similar answers. They worked and script is working perfectly now.